# Reversing Portions of a Doubly Linked Linked (c++)

Tags: c++, loops, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I'm attempting to right a method which reverses a doubly linked list.

```
template <class T>
void List<T>::reverse() {
  reverse(head_, tail_);
}

template <class T>
void List<T>::reverse(ListNode*& startPoint, ListNode*& endPoint) {
  if(startPoint == NULL || endPoint == NULL) return;

  ListNode* currPoint = *&startPoint;
  ListNode* end = endPoint->next;

  while(currPoint != end ) {
    ListNode* tmp = currPoint->next;
    currPoint->next = currPoint->prev;
    currPoint->prev = tmp;

    if(tmp == end) {
      endPoint = startPoint;
      startPoint = currPoint;
    }

    currPoint = tmp;
  }
}
```

So, `head_` and `tail_` are the pointers to the beginning and end of the DLL. The actual process of reversing the list should be fairly simple - reverse the `prev` and `next` pointer for every ListNode in the sequence.

As you can see, I'm attempting to make it so that the second method can reverse any sub-part of the DLL.  I'll be using the second method in other methods, but for now my only goal is to make it work for reversing the entire list.  I think that the biggest issue is that `head_` isn't being updated appropriately, since nothing is present in the when I print the list.

When I print my fairly basic test it simply shows:

```
Expected:   < 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0 >
Actual:     < >
```

One implementation was showing the "9" in the actual output, but I'm fairly certain that was because the first portion of the list was simply being thrown away.

Comment: Use the debugger to step through your program to see where your code is failing.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I've set a break point and stepped through the function, but all gdb shows is the memory address of the list and not the values within the list, so I can't actually tell how it's executing.

Comment: `ListNode* currPoint = *&startPoint;` Shouldnt this be `ListNode* currPoint = *startPoint;`

Comment: Also, did you first try to reverse an entire linked list without any arguments to a `reverse` function?  In other words, the run-of-the-mill reversal of an entire linked list?  If you're not able to write that function, then jumping in trying to write a generic reversal isn't going to work out too well.  If you did write such a function, what is the difference between that function and the one you're showing us, besides the two arguments?

Comment: You should also see what happens to the `next` of the `prev` of `startNode` and `prev` of the `next` of `endNode`. Ideally, there should be another variable storing `start = startNode->prev` . So at the end, you do `if(start !==NULL) start->next = endNode` and `if(end != NULL) end->prev = startNode`

Comment: i haven't gotten to deep into reading this but im pretty sure `*&p` is the same as `p`

Comment: Kaleb, the main tragedy is that you hack code. Go and get a piece of paper and write down your idea and design the algorithm to archive your idea. go from a rough definition to more granular versions. at a last step you can use pseudo-code. this will help later on to maintain your software (yes - software is more the code)

Comment: If you store the data in each node as a pointer to memory, swapping the pointers would be a good thing to do instead of manipulating `prev` and `next`. `swap[first, last]; swap[first + 1, last - 1] ...`

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify the problem into three steps :

1. Store prev of startpoint and next of endpoint, and make them point to nullptr.
2. Reverse the sublist using the same approach which is used for a full length of linked list.
3. Connect start and end nodes of reversed sublist with the stored values  in step 1.

This way

```
[prev] startpoint  ... endpoint [nxt]

[prev]   (nullptr) startpoint... endpoint (nullptr)   [nxt]

[prev]   (nullptr) reverse(startpoint...endpoint) (nullptr)   [nxt]

[prev] begin(reversed-sublist) ...end(reversed-sublist)  [nxt]
```